# how to get senders address - TransactionByHash goeth

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum

How to get sender/from address from TransactionByHash function using goeth client.

I am exploring go ethereum client and I am listing transaction details like block number,transaction hash , gas price , to(contract address) . But there is no from/sender address in raw transaction.

Answer (score 1):

For it took more than 2 hours to find out solution . Finally I can get from address using "AsMessage"

```
   msg, err := txr.AsMessage(types.LatestSignerForChainID(txr.ChainId()),big.NewInt(1))

   if err != nil {
     log.Fatalf("could not fetch msg: %v\n", err)
   }

   fmt.Println("Sender Address : %s",msg.From().Hex())
```